# Can a 650 nm 250 mW diode laser remove the first layer of a PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

Basically I’m trying to make a DIY laser engraver using the specified diode laser, which I’ve seen people successfully engrave more “forgiving” materials such as wood or cardboard.

I was wondering that if I were to engrave a certain design to a PCB (one side), will it work?

This is the board I want to engrave the design on:  [Laminated PCB board 10x15cm](https://www.sigmanortec.ro/en/laminated-pcb-board-10x15cm?SubmitCurrency=1&id_currency=3)

[image]

Comment: In [this page](https://laserengravingtips.com/can-you-laser-engrave-copper/) and [here](https://www.barchlaser.com/fiber-laser-settings-for-engraving-copper/) they are using lasers in the 10W and 30W range for engraving.

Comment: As in *remove all of at least 17 μm of copper*? I'd be surprised.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You might wonder about the downvote for your question. Your question is not easy to answer, because it is too broad. It encompasses a whole design process for some sort of production machinery you want to build. Ask more specifically and add links to the examples you are referring to.

Comment: Bear in mind that copper needs to be heated to 2562 degrees C to be vaporised.

Comment: What if I apply something over the PCB such as photo resistive film, or paint, then engrave my design on that and then etch?

Comment: @VictorBan photoresist is likely to work.  Here's a [blog post](https://hackaday.com/2017/08/22/laser-etching-pcbs/) of someone using this technique.   [And another](https://www.instructables.com/Create-High-Quality-PCBs-at-Home-With-Cheap-Laser-/).

Comment: [this site](https://all3dp.com/2/laser-etching-metal-what-to-know-to-get-started/#:~:text=Laser%20etching%20metal%20is%20possible,least%2060%20W%20of%20power.) says 60 watts minimum. Have you done any research on-line?

Comment: Another direction you may want to consider, if you're not too attached to the idea of using a laser for the PCB, is instead milling it with a CNC machine. I made one a couple years ago for that purpose using parts salvaged from an old 3D printer along with a dremel and some 3D printed parts. See https://reprap.org/wiki/PCB_Milling for some examples of that.

Answer (score 13):

A 250mW CW laser remove copper? Not the remotest of chances.

You could use it to expose photoresist and then develop and etch though. But not with a 650nm laser diode (see comment by @tobalt). A (relatively common) 405nm laser diode should work, though even shorter wavelength would be better.

Comment: Could you explain more? Sorry I’m kind of new to electronics.

Comment: There is simply not enough power to ablate 1oz copper away. Much of the laser light will reflect and the rest will just slightly warm the PCB material. Have a look at LPKF to see how it can be done and compare. You may not like the results anyway, copper ablates at a very high temperature compared to where the substrate will be damaged so you would need a very high and controlled peak power.

Comment: So basically if I put a photo resistive film on it, then engrave my design on that, after developing and etching it will work the same as a normal PCB?

Comment: Expose the photoresist and develop. You can use dry film photoresist and 'washing soda' to develop. Lots of DIY info on the internet.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!

Comment: Good luck exposing photoresist with a red laser though. You might be able to heat it to its crosslinking threshold though. So it will work as a negative type resist (sort of), but will be hard to strip afterwards.

Comment: @tobalt True! Edited.

Comment: Would a 2000mW 445nm laser work? Its pretty much the only one I can found in my country, and it’s about 40$ so I don’t know if it’s a scam or not. Name: Laser for Mini 3-Axis CNC Engraving Machine Sculpture PVC, PBC, wood, Chigods, 445nm 2000MW TTL PWM

Comment: The Chinese laser engravers based on diodes are usually specified in terms of power *input* to the diode, light power output might be 1/5 or 1/8 or something like that, I have not looked closely, but I think that's plenty of power. The wavelength is iffy though, see [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Varun-Ahuja-2/post/What_kind_of_light_source_should_be_used_while_working_for_eg_weighing_with_photosensitive_chemicals/attachment/59d64396c49f478072eac182/AS%3A273811209949186%401442293087685/download/DuPont_Safe+lighting+for+Photopolymers.pdf) document. I think I'd look harder.

Comment: There is another one with 405nm and 1000mW from some site Ampul. Its ~65€, is this better?

Comment: 405nm is better than 445nm, yes.

Comment: So this one is good for engraving the photoresistant film on the copper, leaving me to only develop and etch the board?

Comment: Exposing, not engraving. Sort of like a really 'slow' photographic film. But you might be happier to just make a transparency with a printer (has to be quite opaque) and expose it to the sun and avoid the laser entirely.

Answer (score 5):

A prototyping laser ([LPKF Protolaser H4](https://e-katalog.lkpp.go.id/katalog/produk/detail/67727488?lang=id&type=general)) Has a 1064nm 16W laser, so I'd imagine you'd need at least something with that power level and also with the correct optics (~1mil laser dot). As I understand FR4 and copper being oblated by a laser need an air filtering system to filter toxic gasses.

Comment: Also my understanding is that while it's easy enough to buy laser modules which can be assembled to a moving gantry, they tend to be "optimistically rated". A few years ago a 10W laser was a major research investment, and there is absolutely no way that spending a few 10s of dollars etc. on something labelled "15W" will get you anything equivalent.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd diode laser bars aren't on the tens of dollars scale, but they're only one order of magnitude past that, especially if you take a bit of a gamble on ebay etc. Buy a fibre-coupled one and that takes care of gantry mounting very easily. The real problem is if you want to etch copper, you need a pulsed laser with very high peak power to ablate the material. Even if you could get enough CW laser power you'd just melt it.