# Is there a way to create PCBs with very cheap laser module?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I am quite new to electrical engineering, and I want to progress by creating PCBs. Unfortunately, I do not have the budget to buy a laser cutter to engrave PCB boards, so I was wondering if there would be a certain approach if I were to use a small, cheap diode laser, take a 650 nm and 250 mW one for example. I should mention I only want to build simple PCBs for small circuits for now. Thank you, I am looking forward to learn.

Comment: You might find your answer here: [Can a 650 nm 250 mW diode laser remove the first layer of a PCB?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/679487/can-a-650-nm-250-mw-diode-laser-remove-the-first-layer-of-a-pcb)

Comment: So, basically, the answer is no?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. But @SpehroPefhany wrote something about a 405 nm laser diode that might work.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, a [stripboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripboard) might do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Are you interested in fabricating PCBs at home, or just at getting the PCBs?

In the first case, I have no idea about laser. There are several solutions based on printing on some material (transparent plastic or special materials), then applying it to a raw PCB (isolation or ironing), then using some chemicals to etch away the excess copper. CNC milling on a small CNC is also classical.

If you just want to get the PCBs as cheaply as possible (and you don't plan on lots of PCBs, and you are in no hurry), then I would advise you order them from low cost PCB manufacturers. As long as you keep standard parameters and small sizes (usually bellow 10x10cm, 2 layers), it costs nearly nothing (about the same price as a raw PCB, excepted that it is finished, and if the quality isn't superb, it's still better than what you would achieve at home). For example, on JLCPCB, you can get a 2 layers PCB 10x10cm for 2$ + 1.5$ shipping (if you accept the slowest shipping option).

I would say that now a days, fabricating the PCBs at home is only usefully if it is for the fun of it, or if you want to get them quickly (you can get PCBs cheaply, or fast, but I haven't found anything fast and cheap so far)

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, in my country there are little to no PCB manufacturers, and if I were to order from popular ones like PCB way, shipping would cost about 50€.

Comment: Without knowing your country, it's hard to search for the shipping costs. But are you sure no manufacturer offers anything bellow 50€? I checked for some random countries arround the world for JLCPCB, and the most expensive county had its cheapest shipping option at 23$ (still a lot, but only half of what you found). Also, have a look if there is a fablab near where you live. If you say there is no/nearly no PCB manufacturer in your country, then I suppose it's likely that in your country repairing is often cheap, so check the repair shops if they can do the PCBs for you.

Comment: 47$ shipping to Romania from PCB Way, didn’t check other manufacturers as most often these are the shipping costs to my country.

Comment: Then check out JLCPCB : if you accept 18 buisness days for shipping, you get it for 1.32€ (or <9€ for 10 buisness days, or <17€ for 7)

Comment: Interesting, to be fair I have never seen such low prices before. I also found a small DIY cnc mill that uses a spindle motor, I’m wondering if that would work for what I’m trying to do. Github [link](https://github.com/Shortcircuitboards/PCB-CNC)

Comment: @GabrielStan I rectified the -1 status you got on the question. The CNC link you provide seems doable. (I already have two 3D printers here, so easy for me to print what's needed if I were also interested.) You know your situation best. Best wishes moving forward.